# Match column values and ignoring special characters in PostgreSQL 11.0

Tags: postgresql, sql-like

I have following table in PostgreSQL 11.0

```
name                                            identifier  name_matched
anti-angin® formula                             3792673     anti angin
anti-angin® formula                             3792673     anti angin
arava® 20 mg tablets                            D25155      arava 20 mg
nifedipine extended release tablets 60 mg       23766       nifedipine
```

I using following query to match name and name_matched values.

```
select * from tbl
where name ilike '%' || name_matched || '%'
```

Above query only give row4 as an output. How can I modify the query to fetch all four rows (ignoring special characters and then match the strings)

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from tbl
where
  array(select x[1] from regexp_matches(name_matched, '([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 'g') as x) <@
  array(select x[1] from regexp_matches(name, '([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 'g') as x);
```

or to make it shorter:

```
create function regexp_matches_array(astr text, apattern text)
  returns text[]
  language sql
  immutable
  strict
as $func$
  select array_agg(x[1]) from regexp_matches(astr, apattern, 'g') as x
$func$

select * from tbl
where
  regexp_matches_array(name_matched, '([a-zA-Z0-9]+)') <@
  regexp_matches_array(name, '([a-zA-Z0-9]+)');
```

Note that it does not taking in account the words order.

Comment: could you please explain what '<@' does?

Comment: @rshar `<@` compares two arrays: is the left side is subset of the right side. More here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

Answer (score 0):

This should work for the value combinations shown in your sample data.  Given that you need to work around `-` characters, there may be other cases you need to handle.  If any turn up, comment, and I will see if I can help you work through them.

```
select *
  from tbl
 where replace(regexp_replace(name, '[^A-Za-z0-9 -]', ''), '-', ' ') ~*
       replace(regexp_replace(name_matched, '[^A-Za-z0-9 -]', ''), '-', ' ')
;
```